# I can't bring up a blank activity once i'm in a navigation bar activity

Tags: android

I started an application and I want to bring up a new activity in order to make a form for the database. However, I can't seem to switch from the activity that has a navigation bar, to an empty activity. When I run it and press the "Add a new parachute" button the app crashes.

I have already made the switch from my launching activity which is an empty activity with two buttons, to the activity with the menu. So, I know to add it to the manifest and I even copied the code and modified the names of the class and layout.

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView;

```
private TextView mTextMessage;
DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private Button btnAdd, btnViewData;
private EditText editText;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_chutes:
            { mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_parachutes);
                return true;}
            case R.id.navigation_jump:
            {mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_jump);
                return true;}
            case R.id.navigation_settings:
            {mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_settings);
                return true;}
        }
        return false;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
}
public void greenDay(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewForm.class));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must obtain the context of where the application is at this moment to open a new activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(**v.getContext()**, NewForm.class));
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The actual problem was at the switch from the Main activity to this activity. It was done through an intermediary activity that would also call the layout main_menu. That's why it couldn't pass to my NewForm activity through the current context